How to sum the latest values of sam field data values of multiple devices in Apache IoTDB?
Is there any way in Apache IoTDB to sum the last values of data points with the same field name for multiple devices? The structure of query statement should be similar to select sum(last time series) from root.station.**. I checked the official guide and seems that there's no direct command examples for this case, so I want to ask are there any other ways I can achieve this?

If you want to achieve this kind of query in Apache IoTDB, there is currently no direct function to write single statement to do that. This kind of query result needs to be sum up after the last query is returned.
